# why does express-ejs-layouts wrap up my other pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i am learing routing in node js. First day when i write this code it was working.
after 3 days it showing an error that express is wraping up your page.
I find the solution and now its working.
But I want to know why Express Wrap up your page?

```
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();


//view engine
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{

      res.render('welcome')
})



const port = process.env.port || 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`server is up on ${port}`));
```

But if I declare my page as layout and set it to false then it will work.

```
app.set('layout register', false);

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{

      res.render('welcome', {layout: 'welcome')
})
```